# SignTool returns "The filename, directory name, or volume label...." error

Tags: signtool

I am trying to code-sign my dlls using the SignTool and Post Build Events. I use this method:

```
“C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool.exe” sign /f “$(ProjectDir)archilabCertificate.pfx” /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode /p “mypassword” "$(TargetPath)"
```

my certificate is located in the specified folder.

```
ProjectDir = D:\Google Drive\Work\GrimshawTools\GrimshawRibbon\GrimshawRibbon
TargetPath = C:\ProgramData\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2016\GrimshawRibbon.dll
```

There is nothing that I can think of that could be causing this issue. I checked these paths about 100 times. I tried moving the PFX file to C drive. I tried specifying direct path to the file instead of using shorthands. I can't think of anything. Else. Ideas? How can I even debug this to find exactly what's causing the issue? I have other post builds that are working just fine.

Cheers!

Ps. I use the same certificate on my home machine and it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ **”** ] character is invalid! use [ **"** ] character.
`[“]C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86\signtool.exe[”] sign /f “$(ProjectDir)archilabCertificate.pfx” /t http://timestamp.comodoca.com/authenticode /p [“]mypassword[”] "$(TargetPath)"`

Comment: You are really saving my life here. I would have never seen this. Lesson learned. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the point if someone is looking for it.

I faced a similar issue, but in my case, I had the timestamp address within "<". Found a MS article which says:
**"The system does not accept the keyboard combination Alt+0 through Alt+32 or the following characters: \ \ / [ ] : | < > + ; = . ? "**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms832054.aspx